# Multiple sed commands without create a separate script, and without use -e

Tags: shell, sed, scripting

I am using sh to write a script, and I want to replace parts of a file. I am using sed, since it is simple to do a substitution.

Now I noticed that with sh, I cannot wrap the sed commands on multiple lines, like I would do in a script. So I am using the sed -e option, and a \ at the end of each line.

Is there a more efficient way to write a sequence of sed commands, that has to be executed on a file, and save the output to another?

Or the only options are either to write a script and call it with the -f flag, or to make multiple lines using the -c flag and the \ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes to enclose the sed commands:

```
sed '
    s/this/that/
    s/foo/bar/
    # and so on
' file
```

To handle variables, you need to jump out of the single quotes:

```
sed '
    s/this/'"$variable"'/
    s/foo/bar/
    # and so on
' file
```

Comment: Works great, thanks Glenn! Although there is an issue: if you place in a line a variable, it won't be converted, but printed as literal: s/this/$variable will replace this with $variable, not with its content.

Comment: my bad; forgot to wrap the variable in quotes

Comment: You can also separate commands with [`;`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-61): `echo "good bye john" | sed 's/good bye/hello/; s/john/world/'`